# Executing stringified python function from python script

Tags: python

I'd like to use Python's eval in a way similar to that of Javascript. In Javascript, I can eval something like this:

```
const myfunc = eval('function(arg1, arg2) { ...... }');
myfunc(1, 2);
```

**First of all, I'll start by saying that the functions being run are NOT from userland - only the admins on our team are writing the functions, and it's a core part of our product architecture. I'm aware of the security implications :)**

Some things that I have thought of myself include:

1. During runtime (so the format is preserved), using a library to convert the code into a single-liner. But I don't really want to rely on a third party library for doing this as that introduces potential future security holes.
2. Temporarily saving the script to a file and importing that file dynamically using `importlib`. But then I end up with a potentially weird server state if file management commands fail or are used improperly, and I'm paranoid that I'll call the wrong script and execute the wrong code.

I don't really *love* either of these options. I know that I could make them both work if I had to, but was hoping to get input from people who know Python much better than I do.

Comment: Off-topic, but in JavaScript that would be better as `const myfunc = new Function("arg1", "arg2", "......")`. MDN's ["Do not ever use `eval`!"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!) gives the reasoning.

Comment: @Amadan thanks, that was a good read.

Answer (score 0):

I used the 2nd option - its much better than eval.

Files containing entire class and its functions can be written at runtime and executed. 
Using some scheme where you write a different class name each time and match the class name and function name can ensure you call the correct script when needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? So, supposing my function is stored in the database as a string (not a hard requirement), you're suggesting to output it into a file under a unique class name, import it, and execute it?

Comment: I had loaded python modules from files and found that I could handle dynamically written multi line indented code (with try catch blocks as well), better than executing it with eval. My point was that you need not fear calling the wrong code with this approach. If writing files is not a good approach for your design, that is another thing.

Comment: I think that this is probably the correct approach, I agree. It seems like there are some mechanics that need to be thought through, but unless any other interesting ideas are posted here I'll probably go with this option.